# How to protect an imported Win32 DLL into a .NET application from memory issues

Tags: .net, winapi, interop

I have a C# application that needs to use a legacy Win32 DLL.  The DLL is almost its own application, it has dialogs, operations with hardware, etc.  When this DLL is imported and used, there are a couple of problems that occur:

1. Dragging a dialog (not a Windows
   system dialog, but one created by
   the DLL) across the managed code application
   causes the UI to not repaint. 
   Further it generates a system out of
   memory exception from various UI
   controls.
2. The performance is incredibly
   slow.
3. There seems to be no way to
   unload the DLL so the memory never
   gets cleaned up.  When we close our
   managed application, we get another memory
   exception.

At the moment we import each method call as such:

```
[DllImport("dllname.dll",
    EntryPoint = "MethodName", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
```

Comment: I assume you have tested calling the DLL from non-managed code, and it behaves properly?

Comment: Yes, the earlier version of what we replaced with managed code was non-managed.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an exe wrapper (possibly unmanaged) that exposes an API for your new application to use.

Another possible solution is to create a second UI thread that just handles the troublesome DLL. I lean more towards the exe wrapper, though, because that approach deals with OOM more gracefully (you can restart the process if necessary).

Comment: I considered the exe wrapper, but the unmanaged dll must be invoked in the same process as the managed app.

Comment: Why not in the same process? - users will not know if it is so

Comment: @Mark: exe wrappers are useful whenever you have a buggy component out of your control that crashes the entire process (e.g., with OOM). Restarting a subprocess on failure is not too difficult; I had to do this years ago with an Oracle client dll that kept crashing our 24x7 factory automation system. The users don't see any difference but it makes a big difference to the OS (different exe has its own memory space, and won't crash the parent exe).

Comment: Stephen I was agreeing with you for those reasons - my question was to @Eric

Comment: It is because both the managed app and the unmanaged dll need access to the same com objects